# updating the view from handler in eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am new to eclipse e4 application.
I have a menu item open handler, when i click on it the filedialog appears and I can select the files and I should display the selected files on the view part.

Can anyone please help me how to update the view from the handler?

Comment: Pure e4 does not have views. Is this an `MPart` you have made that looks like a view or are you actually using 3.x `ViewPart`?

Comment: I am using MPart. In the Mpart i am using Tableviewer to display the file names that i hav selected in the FileDialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `EPartService` to find your part in the handler:

```
@Execute
void execute(EPartService partService)
{
  MPart part = partService.findPart("part id ");

  // TODO use FileDialog

  YourClass yourClass = (YourClass)part.getObject();

  // TODO call a method in YourClass to set the table input
}
```

where `YourClass` is the class you defined for the part. You then just need to add a method to `YourClass` that you can call to set the table input. "part id" is the id you specified for the MPart in the application model.